# Stack multiple images on top of one another using Flex Box

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox

I'm using flex box to create a rotating image gallery and I need the images to all stack on top of each other, one behind the other.  I can do this with positioning the images as absolute, but that messes up the containing flex box so the images appear outside of the container.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

  setInterval(function() {
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
      .fadeOut(1000)
      .next()
      .fadeIn(1000)
      .end()
      .appendTo('#slideshow');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
#slideshow {
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: fit-content;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#slideshow>div {
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

#slideshow div img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.ncat.edu/caes/cooperative-extension/programs/sfw-files/gallery-photos/checking-copy---resized.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.ncat.edu/caes/cooperative-extension/programs/sfw-files/gallery-photos/phyllis-kesling-sfoy-candidate_0074-copy-copy---resized.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And to make life easier, here's a JSFiddle Link

[JSFiddle Example of what I'm doing](https://jsfiddle.net/Kaanha/29xLjayu/1/)

How can I stack the images using a flexbox? I've set up a small JSFiddle here for you to see what I'm doing...as you can see the images DO rotate but the other image appears next to the first image...

Thanks in advance to all that help!

Comment: you're trying to make what we call a carousel? If so, there's a lot of ways of doing it. here's the most basic one https://christianheilmann.com/2015/04/08/keeping-it-simple-coding-a-carousel/

Answer (score 0):

You should use position: absolute to stack things on each other

```
 #slideshow {
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 }

 #slideshow > div {
    position: absolute;
 }

 #slideshow div img {
    max-width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: That puts it outside of the container div, however, as I mentioned in my original question.  I was doing position absolute, but they floated outside the container div since Position absolute takes the elements out of the document's flow.  I can't use Position Absolute.

Comment: It is not possible to stack elements on each other using flex. You can use position: absolute and then javaScript to calculate and set height of container based on image height or just set some static height value.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to do this using flex, as flex is designed to lay things out around each other.  However, if you switch to using flex, you can set this up very easily: https://codepen.io/adamjamesturner/pen/VwYoRVp

You just need to change the css to:

```
#slideshow {
     margin: 50px auto;
     position: relative;
     display: grid;        // Change here
     height: fit-content;
     align-items: center;
     width: 90%;
     box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 }

 #slideshow>div {
     margin: 10px;
     grid-rows: 1/2;    // Change here
     grid-columns: 1/2; // Change here
 }

#slideshow div img {
     max-width: 100%;
}
```